# How can I use platform-agnostic keymappings in PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I'm trying to contribute to [SpacePeacock](https://github.com/ShawnMcCool/PHPStorm-SpacePeacock), a shared repo for some custom settings for PHPstorm. Currently the keymappings are all Linux/PC (CTRL) and I use Mac (CMD).

Is there any way to make keymappings platform agnostic (e.g. like Sublime Text's "Super")?